# Is it possible to convert multiple local regions in a matrix to a new matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

For example, if I have a `10×10` matrix, and I have a list of `n` coordinates in that matrix, I would like to take a `3×3` region surrounding each coordinate, resize it to be a length `9` vector, and then stack all the vectors into a `9×n` matrix.  I know I could write a for loop to do this but that seems gross, though probably what I'll end up doing.

Comment: first thought: you can write a loop that runs `n` times instead of running `10*10` times. The number of coordinates will most certainly be less then `10*10` (or the number of elements in your matrix). This will save some computational time since you can vectorize pretty much every other task. In pseudocode would be something like `for i=1:n ; extract 3x3 region surrounding coordinate *i* ; concatenate matrix`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the coordinates are already in index form, you could use this:

```
m = 10;
A = rand(m);
cc = [23; 47; 64];
ind = bsxfun(@plus, [(-1:1) - m, (-1:1), (-1:1) + m], cc);
newVals = A(ind);
```

Or first convert coordinates into index form:

```
c1 = [3 3; 7 5; 4 7];
cc = sub2ind(size(A), c1(:,1), c1(:,2));
```

Of course, this does not check for coordinates being at the edges of the matrix, and it will throw an error if any of the coordinates is.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is any more performant than a for loop but you could do it doing some calculations on the index values.

```
data = magic(5);

%//     17    24     1     8    15
%//     23     5     7    14    16
%//      4     6    13    20    22
%//     10    12    19    21     3
%//     11    18    25     2     9

%// The coordinates you want to sample at (row, col)
coords = [2 3; 3 2; 2 4];

%// Determine the row and column offsets to apply for a 3x3 block
[rowOffset, colOffset] = ndgrid(-1:1,-1:1);

%// Compute the rows and columns included in each block centered t each point
rows = bsxfun(@plus, coords(:,1).', rowOffset(:));
cols = bsxfun(@plus, coords(:,2).', colOffset(:));

%// Convert to absolute linear index and sample data at these regions
newdata = data(sub2ind(size(data), rows, cols));

%//   24    23     1
%//    5     4     7
%//    6    10    13
%//    1     5     8
%//    7     6    14
%//   13    12    20
%//    8     7    15
%//   14    13    16
%//   20    19    22
```

That being said, depending on what you want to do with each of those groups, you *could* potentially use convolution or something to accomplish the same thing.